# PySpark - to_date funtion returning NULL

Tags: azure, pyspark, databricks

I was trying to cast my StringType() column to a new DateType() column but it's giving me NULL as output.

[Sample Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7hQW.png)

Getting Output as below:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G23vX.png)

Tried the below Code:

```
spark.sql("set spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy=LEGACY")
workerdf = worker_df.withColumn('JOINING_DATE', to_date(col('JOINING_DATE_STR'), "DD-MM-YYYY"))
```

Comment: Convert images to plain text please.

Answer (score 0):

Use proper date format to convert `dd-MM-yyyy`

**Sample Code:**

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_date, col
spark.sql("set spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy=LEGACY")
df1 = df1.withColumn('JOINING_DATE', to_date(col('JOINING_DATE STR'), 'dd-MM-yyyy'))
df1.show()
```

**Execution and output:**

[image]